# Bulk replacement of char

Tags: java, string

I am having a domain object with over 90 attributes. In all these attributes there are `.`, which I want to replace with an empty string.

I could do now:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    list.get(i).getProp1().replace(".", "");
    list.get(i).getProp2().replace(".", "");
    //yadadada ...
    list.get(i).getProp90().replace(".", "");
}
```

However, that is extremely boring and takes a lot of code to write. Is there a way to do this much more elegantly and faster?

I appreciate your ideas

Comment: You do realize the code you've got at the moment isn't actually changing the property of the field, right? It's calling `replace` on the string, and then ignoring the result...

Comment: Why don't you do it in the setter method of every prop? Also, what Jon said.

Comment: If "domain object" is yours, then use List of properties (List<Property> list = new ArrayList<Property>()) and get them by list.get(i).getProperty(j) (Property getProperty(int index) { return list.get(index); }), j=1;90

Comment: The world of Java: `reflection` is magic

Comment: If at all possible, you might want to reconsider the way you store the properties themselves in your objects. If you have e.g. an ArrayList or HashMap, you might transverse that as simple as your list of objects. Not necessarily performance improving (nor reducing) but much easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

What about making a method updateProp (since that's what you need) in your Domain class like this:

```
public void updateProp(int index) {
    prop[index] = prop[index].replace(".", "");
}
```

and then calling it in a loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    for(int j=0; j < prop.length; j++) { /*use a getter, instance or class 
                                     reference for obtaining prop.length*/
        list.get(i).updateProp(j);
    }
}
```

Storing the Prop in its own Object could also do the trick, but I guess it'll break more code than it will fix.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use java reflection:

```
    Method[] methods = DomainObject.class.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        if (method.getName().startsWith("getProp")) {
            String result = (String) method.invoke(object, new Object[0]);
            result = result.replace(".", "");
            Method setter = DomainObject.class.getMethod(method.getName()
                    .replace("get", "set"), String.class);
            setter.invoke(object, result);
        }
    }
```

Also don't forget String is immutable, the replace method doesn't change it, the call simply returns the changed version.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot modify your object (maybe is auto-generated or something) you can achieve your goal through reflection:

```
for(MyObject a: list){
    Field[] fields = MyObject.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field f : fields) {
        try {
            if (f.get(a) instanceof String) {
                String str = ((String) f.get(a)).replace(".", "");
                f.set(a, str);
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to modify the values of your objects you can create The Monster:

```
List<Map<String, String>> monster = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
for(MyObject a: list){
    Field[] fields = MyObject.class.getDeclaredFields();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (Field f : fields) {
        try {
            if (f.get(a) instanceof String) {
                String str = ((String) f.get(a)).replace(".", "");
                map.put(f.getName(), str);
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    monster.add(map);
}
```

Now you have a beatiful list of maps for fields created through reflection. You can access to prop1 of first object via

```
String obj1prop1 = monster.get(0).get("prop1"); //Value of prop1 for first object in list.
```

Answer (score 1):

You're suggesting that you have a Java class which has up to 90 properties with a consistently incorrectly formatted data field. This question is possibly an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

There is a reason the attributes are stored with a `.`, and a reason you need them without the `.`

By understanding these reasons better, and their context, a cleaner solution will present itself.

For example, is the removal of the `.` purely for display purposes? Perhaps consider a generic function at the point of output to strip the `.`'s

Or maybe it's some kind of behaviour side-effect during data capture, in which case this needs to be part of an input filter.

Or is this a one-off ETL routine? In which case perhaps it could be done on the data columns direct by some generic SQL or grep / sed script.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way for me would be to create a method in your Object (the one from your List) and in this method, you directly change all the properties as you did here. Than you call your method instead of all of those.
The treatment will be directly on your Object ;)

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    list.set(i,list.get(i).update());
}
```

in your Object :

```
public void update()
{
    prop1 = prop1.replace(".","");
    etc for all the properties
}
```

Or you could use something like : `Field[] getFields()` if your attribute are public.

But actually, I think you should do this replace when you are creating your object, so before you already add it in the list. It would be better.